# Creating and Populating the Time dimension

Tags: sql, oracle, dimensional-modeling

My shift_date column of my  shift table has all the dates of the shift requests recieved by the agency.It contains other columns which shows whether the shift was filled or cancelled. I want to use this to create a time dimension and link to the fact table to find out how many shifts were filled each month,cancelled in a quarter,etc. i have created the time table as below. I am doing it in SQL developer and to understand dimensional modelling which I am having trouble getting my head around.

my shift table:

```
shift_date |shift_status|request_id|
-----------------------------------------
 09-01-2011|Filled      |8899
21-01-2011 |Cancelled   |6677
```

and so on.
I created a time dimension table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE "DIM_TIME" 
       (    "TIME_KEY" NUMBER(10,0), 
        "FULL_DATE" DATE, 
        "DAY_NAME" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE), 
        "DAY_OF_WEEK" NUMBER(5,0), 
        "DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH" NUMBER(2,0), 
        "DAY_NAME_ABBREVATED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
        "WEEKDAY_FLAG" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 
        "WEEK_OF_THE_YEAR" NUMBER(5,0), 
        "WEEK_BEGIN_DATE" DATE, 
        "MONTH_NUMBER" NUMBER(3,0), 
        "MONTH_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        "MONTH_ABBREVATED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
        "QUARTER" NUMBER(5,0), 
        "YEAR" NUMBER(5,0), 
        "LAST_DAY_IN_MONTH_FLAG" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
       );
```

how can i extract the dates from the shift_date column to populate this time_dimension table? I am not expecting the whole code but if anyone can point me in the right direction it will be helpful as i am still learning.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This will create the rows in the `DIM_TIME` table:

```
create sequence s_time_key START WITH 1;

insert into dim_time (
  time_key,
  full_date,
  day_name,
  day_of_week,
  day_number_in_month,
  day_name_abbrevated,
  weekday_flag,
  week_of_the_year,
  week_begin_date,
  month_number,
  month_name,
  month_abbrevated,
  quarter,
  year,
  last_day_in_month_flag
)
select
  s_time_key.nextval,
  d,
  to_char(d,'Day'),   --Monday
  to_char(d,'D'),     --1-7, monday=2 in some countries, 1 in others (NLS)
  to_char(d,'DD'),    --1-31
  to_char(d,'Dy'),    --Su, Mo, ...
  decode(to_char(d,'Dy'),'Sa','N','Su','N','Y'),
  to_char(d,'IW'),    --week num ISO standard
--to_char(d,'WW'),    --week num other
  d+1-to_char(d,'D'), --first day in week, depending on NLS
  to_number(to_char(d,'MM')),
  to_char(d,'Month'),
  to_char(d,'MON'),
  to_char(d,'YYYYQ'),
  to_char(d,'YYYY'),
  decode(to_char(d+1,'DD'),'01','Y','N')
from (select distinct shift_date d from shift);
```

- In Oracle 12c, instead of a `sequence` to get the `time_key` column, you could use `create table dim_time ( time_key number(10) generated by default on null as identity, ...` to autoincrement the key.
- The select above will only populate table DIM_TIME with the dates that actually exists in table SHIFT. But often one will want *all* dates in a certain period, for instance all the days Jan 1st 2014 trough 2018 like this: replace the last line in the sql above with this:

.

```
from (
  select d from (
    select to_date('1970','YYYY')+level d from dual connect by level<=366*100
  )
  where to_char(d,'YYYY')
  between 2014 and 2018
);
```

- It's important to learn the `to_char` and `to_date` functions to handle dates in Oracle. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

Comment: Brilliant! This is epic script. I was wondering if i needed as many insert statements as the rows but you saved me. Please I didnt quite understand the logic behind from (
  select d from (
    select to_date('1970','YYYY')+level d from dual connect by level<=366*100
  )
  where to_char(d,'YYYY')
  between 2014 and 2018
); Any chance you can explain? Thanks

Comment: (pls upvote, up arrow top left of answer, if you liked it :-)   Yes, that last part will insert all days `between 2014 and 2018` as it says. Some explanation: `select level from dual connect by level<=366*100;` is just a way in Oracle (recursive `with` could be used instead to make the SQL more compatible to other database systems) to get all numbers from 1 to 36600 - which is at least the number of days in a houndred years. Adding those numbers to Jan 1st 1970 gets all days for a houndred years starting in 1970. The `between` filter returns only those years.

Comment: Got it now! Great stuff..Upvoted too. One last question. what will be the best approach if i want to add one more column say is_holiday to see how many shifts were covered during holidays? should i create a table with all holidays listed for the year 2011?

Comment: You could do that and then perhaps also add a new flag column `holiday_flag` with `Y` or `N` to your current DIM_TIME. If this is international software this is different in other countries and cultures. And as I understand, in many countries (states? municipalities?)  businesses themselves decides their holidays. Creating a table `HOLIDAY_CULTURE` could be the answer where you also should be able to add a DAYS_RELATIVE to easter or idul fitri in many muslim majority countries and keep a separate table where those varying dates are kept for each year.